# Reuse of Java Security settings (policy file) in OSGi

Tags: security, osgi

We migrated our application to an OSGi based application. We are now running on Felix 4.2.1.

Previously we managed our security using the standard Java Security Model using a policy file. This comes down to providing security manager settings as start up parameters to our Java start up process:

```
-Djava.security.policy==.policy -Djava.security.manager
```

Previously, before the migration to OSGi, these exact same security settings were picked up by our application.
Now these security settings don't seem to be applied any more and basically we *lost* all our Java Security settings.

I have searched here, the internet, consulted some books and all suggest solutions similar to as described [here](http://log.illsley.org/2010/11/29/osgi-java-security-manager-and-keeping-things-simple/), basically granting all permissions to OSGi and enable OSGi security.

However I could not find any confirmation this is absolutely needed to have Security enabled. For now I would like to avoid changing our security configuration too much for OSGi and reuse what we have.

So, is there a way to reuse an existing Java Security policy file in an OSGi environment? Or am I missing something trivial here?

Answer (score 0):

For Felix you'll need to also add the felix security bundle. 
A description of it can be found [here](http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-framework-security.html). 
With that enabled you should be safe on re-using your security policies.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The description in the link seems to explain the same as what I describe above and preferably would like to avoid: grant all permissions to OSGi  and configure OSGi security. I am looking for a way to have my current policy picked up by OSGi or seek confirmation that this is in fact not possible and that I need to migrate to OSGi security.

Answer (score 0):

We have never found any 'official' confirmation whether this was needed so in the end we decided to bite the bullet and implement OSGi security.